# Change height of bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I am having a hard time adjusting the height of the bootstrap carousel. If I change the width of the carousel div then I indirectly change the size but I would like the full width with a change in height where half of the image appears and its center in the div element it exists in. Below is the change with the width

```
<div
  id="showcase_carousel"
  class="carousel slide carousel-dark w-75"
  data-bs-ride="carousel"
  style=""
>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to add some css to the `img` tag. With that you can adjust the height of the image and center it.
Something like so:

```
.carousel img {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}
```

The `object-fit: cover;` makes it so that the image will fit and not being stretched out. With `object-position: center;` it centers the image of the view. In this case it centers image on the height of 400px.

Here's a working example: https://www.codeply.com/p/YHBLOvGq5F

Comment: No problem, glad it helped you out!